# Plotted lines gets compressed when plot pie chart with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, pie-chart

In my program first I draw a tree (graph with no cycles) plotting just lines. As yo can see in the figure

[image: Figure of ploted lines]

My problem is that when I plot a pie chart over the same figure, all the plots and pie chart gets compresed, and the box disapears, as you can see in the next figure

[image: Figures compresed after ploting pie chart]

My code basically is:

`from mathplotlib import pyplot as plt
    plt.figure()
    # Plottin a straight line from (0,0) to (1,1) in the (x,y) plane
    X=[0,1]
    Y=[0,1]
    plt.plot(X,Y)
    # Plotng a pie chart
    plt.pie([100],radius=0.5,center=(1/4,3/4))`

Why it happends?
How can I fix it?

Comment: I guess it makes sense to share the actual code, instead of the "basically is" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword Frame in the call to pie() is what you are after.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
X = [0, 1]
Y = [0, 1]
plt.plot(X, Y, color='black', zorder=100)
plt.pie([1], radius=0.5, center=(0.5, 0.5), frame=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]